# simulation and timestep

Tags: simulations, vasicek

Suppose I have a stochastic process i.e. a Vasicek process with parameteres estimated with monthly (RW measure) data and want simulate the process using a daily timestep. Is this a good practice?

Comment: I do not see problems with such timestep.

Answer (score 1):

By estimating the model parameters using monthly data, you will get monthly estimates. Thus, you will need to multiply them by $12$ (or by $\sqrt{12}$ for the volatility) in order to get annual estimates. Once you have done this, you can simulate the model using the timestep $\Delta t=\frac{1}{252}$.